# Passing Variables to unopened forms

Tags: vb.net

I have a log in form. And when I successfully logged in, the log in form closes(not hidden) and the main form will appear with the informations of the user. How can I save the username temporarily into variable for further query? I'm using the username to query for the information of the current user in all forms. When jumping from form-to-form, the previous form closes. So the username stored in a variable in the current form, disappears. 
Passing variables isn't working, maybe because the other forms are not yet opened?

Loginform

```
mainform.username = tbUser.text
```

MainForm

```
Public Class mainform
    Public username as string

    ...Some codes here
End Class
```

When I try to message box it in main form, it shows nothing

Comment: are you using default instance or are you instantiating the forms and then passing the information on. Can you show us how you've attempted this that isn't working?

Comment: I'm using default instances. Like a ready-made forms

Comment: Yes, but you can still instantiate those ready made forms and pass variables to them before ever showing them to the user.

Comment: I'm doing the jumping of forms `anotherform.show() currentform.Close()` and have set the shutdown mode to "when last form closes"

Comment: OK, this is going to get flagged as a conversation. Can you show some code so we can help. You can pass properties even in the default instance but I'm not 100% sure what all is happening in your code to give a more concise answer.

Comment: Edited the question. I'm sorry for the limited codes. Because I'm currently using mobile right now.

Comment: You can arrange your code in this order `mainform.Show() mainform.username = tbUser.Text Me.Close()`

Comment: Already tried it. But still no luck. Maybe I'll do your first suggestion, make it instantiated form.

Comment: That should work. Are you doing something to tbUser before setting mainform.username that might be clearing its .Text property?

Comment: No, nothing. That's exactly the lines in my code. Tried it even in a separate module. Btw, how can I pass variable to instantiated form? `Dim main as new mainform() main.Show()` what should I add?

Comment: Are you entering something into tb.User before passing it on to mainform.username? Because it sounds like you're not. You must have something in the textbox `tbUser.Text` before you can assign that value to the other forms variable.

Comment: I don't know why rearranging the codes, as you've suggested, didn't work. But already solved it. I instantiated it with `Dim main as new mainform()` then `main.username = tbUser.text` then `main.show()` and i have that messagebox code, and the username appeared. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, tbUser has it's value. Tried to messagebox it in the current form and it appears as expected. I don't know why rearranging the lines didn't work. I know that should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access your User data from all your forms create a class with Shared properties. Create the User in your first form.

```
Public Class User
    Friend Sub New()
        'Put back the default constructor
    End Sub
    Friend Sub New(uName As String, uDepartment As String, uAccess As String)
        UserName = uName
        UserDepartment = uDepartment
        AccessLevel = uAccess
    End Sub
    Friend Shared Property UserName As String
    Friend Shared Property UserDepartment As String
    Friend Shared Property AccessLevel As String
End Class
```

Create your user anywhere on your first form.

```
    Dim LoggedInUser As New User("Mary", "Accounting", "Administrator")
    Form2.Show()
    Close()
```

Then on any other form...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show($"The user name is {User.UserName}, their department is {User.UserDepartment}, their Access Level is {User.AccessLevel}.")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Removed constructors from class and added a Private constructor. I believe this makes the class similar to a C# static class.

```
Public Class User
    'A private constructor prevents instantiation
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Friend Shared Property UserName As String
    Friend Shared Property UserDepartment As String
    Friend Shared Property AccessLevel As String
End Class
```

Then in the main form set the properties directly

```
    User.UserName = "Mary"
    User.UserDepartment = "Accounting"
    User.AccessLevel = "Administrator"
    Form2.Show()
    Close()
```

The code in other forms is the same.

Comment: Wow. This is what I was looking for. Tried creating class file and declare `Public username as String` in it but it shows an error `Reference to non-shared member requires an object reference.` I didn't know this is the proper way of doing it. Thank you

Comment: @muyie remove the "shared" shared is used for all instances. But MyFormName.username = "johndoe" would work.

Comment: @EricSchneider The OP wants a single instance. If you remove Shared you will need the correct instance of the class and we are back to passing the user around from from to form.

Comment: Actually, I guess I should have dumped the constructors all-together and just set the properties directly on Users. Silly to use a constructor. :-)